# Trouble with email validation using jQuery validation in WebKit

Tags: jquery, validation, email, forms, webkit

I'm running into a strange issue in WebKit browsers, where the "email" field on my form won't trigger validation by the jQuery validation plugin (using the built-in email method).

Works in FF and IE, but Safari and Chrome don't seem to like it.

I've put together a sample page here with just the form and scripts for debugging:  http://bit.ly/9SFv7r

Would anyone be able to shed some light on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. It's something to do with `<input type="email" />`

Validation works fine in Chrome if you change to `<input type="text" />`

It doesn't seem to be a browser issue, as the validator also doesn't work in Opera 10.61, which supports the email input type.

Not sure if it's an issue with jQuery or the Validator plug-in, as I know that non-supported input types are converted to text fields in non-supportive browsers in the background (which is why it works in Firefox/IE).

Comment: Perfect!  Nice spot there.  From the fourth comment here — http://plugins.jquery.com/node/11076 — looks like it's something to do with the combination of the plugin alongside browsers that support an "email" input type.  For some reason, that combination does not allow for validation on keyup or focus at the moment.